# CSS float height auto adjustments

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have here my CSS code. My problem is that when the content has many things it adjust its height greater than the navigation's height. What i want is when one of this float height adjust it includes the other as well.

```
<div id="main">   
    <div id="navigation"></div>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
</div>
```

CSS code below:

```
#main{
    width: 960px;
    height: 500px;
    margin: auto;
}
#navigation{
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: #C7E1BA;
}
#content{
    float: right;
    width: 740px;
    background-color: #F6E4CC;
    padding: 10px;
}
#content, #navigation {
    height: 100%;

}
#footer{
    clear: both;
    width: 960px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #628B61;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set both `#navigation` and `#content` to `display: table-cell` and then get rid of the `float`'s on both of them. That should do the trick. If you want a minimum height you can just set it on either one of the `div`'s and the other `div` will follow suit. This should work in [all browsers and IE8+](http://caniuse.com/css-table).

```
#navigation{
    width: 200px;
    background-color: #C7E1BA;
}
#content{
    width: 740px;
    background-color: #F6E4CC;
    padding: 10px;
}
#content, #navigation {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Here's a <kbd>**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CwkGq/1/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
#content{
    float: right;
    width: 740px;
    background-color: #F6E4CC;
    padding: 10px;
    display:table;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the same padding to #navigation as that of #content. Edit the CSS class as below

```
#navigation{
    float: left;
    width: 180px;
    background-color: #C7E1BA;
    padding : 10px;
}
```

Comment: this is a good suggestion, but the next problem is the overflowing of #content contents. it overlapped in my footer :(

Answer (score 0):

What a beautiful use case for [FlexBox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)!

```css
#main{
  width: 960px;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
#navigation{
  min-height: 400px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #C7E1BA;
}
#content{
  width: 760px;
  background-color: #F6E4CC;
}

#footer{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #628B61;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">   
    <div id="navigation"></div>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
</div>
```